# Can't change activity name with fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I can't change the activity name in the bar when using fragments

```
public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_scenarios_list_equipements);


        context = this;

        setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name)+" - " + getString(R.string.scenarios));

    }
```

when I toast it it gives me the right name but it doesn't do anything when I use setTitle
any ideas?

EDIT: [image: When I run code]

Comment: By bar do you mean action bar?

Comment: Is that code in your fragment or your activity?  It should be in the activity...

Comment: yes the code is in the activity

Comment: So what happens when that code runs?

Comment: I added a screenshot so you can see, it just has a blank header

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to tell it where to get the string from (resources that is)...  try this:

```
setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)+" - " + getResources().getString(R.string.scenarios))
```

Comment: no luck, I toasted getTitle() and I get the right String, it's just displaying it that's the problem apparently